# how to add labels when ingesting data into neo4j from Kafka with neo4j-streams?

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka

I have a stream of Kafka messages that look like this:

```
{
  "ts": 1574487125808,
  "uid": "Cxxzpx3A12ai2Ckn4f",
  "id_orig_h": "10.0.1.19",
  "id_orig_p": 53312,
  "id_resp_h": "10.0.1.16",
  "id_resp_p": 8080,
  "proto": "tcp",
  "service": "http",
  "duration": 9.636139154434204,
  "orig_bytes": 760,
  "resp_bytes": 220,
  "conn_state": "SF",
  "local_orig": true,
  "local_resp": true,
  "missed_bytes": 0,
  "history": "ShADadfF",
  "orig_pkts": 6,
  "orig_ip_bytes": 1080,
  "resp_pkts": 5,
  "resp_ip_bytes": 488
}
```

I'm using the [neo4j-streams](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/3.5/consumer/) (v.3.5.4) consumer to build a graph of the messages. Neo4j version is v.3.5.12. I added this to `neo4j.conf`:

```
streams.sink.enabled=true 
streams.sink.topic.cypher.conn=MERGE (origin:Origin {id: event.id_orig_h}) MERGE (response:Response {id: event.id_resp_h}) MERGE (origin)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(response)
```

... and it builds the graph. Great!

I'd like to add the ip address labels to the nodes, and am struggling to get that bit working. I've tried adding `SET` commands, e.g.

```
streams.sink.topic.cypher.conn=MERGE (origin:Origin {id: event.id_orig_h}) SET origin:event.id_orig_h MERGE (response:Response {id: event.id_resp_h}) SET response:event.id_resp_h MERGE (origin)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(response)
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
ErrorData(originalTopic=conn, timestamp=1574493915864, partition=0, offset=617872, exception=org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Invalid input '.': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, a property map, a relationship pattern, ',', FROM GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 86 (offset: 85))
"UNWIND {events} AS event MERGE (origin:Origin {id: event.id_orig_h}) SET origin:event.id_orig_h MERGE (response:Response {id: event.id_resp_h}) SET response:event.id_resp_h MERGE (origin)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(response) "
                                                                                      ^, key=null, value={"ts":1574493904862,"uid":"C04y9u1KAZfAIHVVu","id_orig_h":"10.0.1.61","id_orig_p":53790,"id_resp_h":"10.0.1.1","id_resp_p":53,"proto":"udp","service":"dns","duration":0.0001399517059326172,"orig_bytes, executingClass=class streams.kafka.KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer)
        at streams.service.errors.KafkaErrorService.report(KafkaErrorService.kt:37)
        at streams.kafka.KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer.executeAction(KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer.kt:95)
        at streams.kafka.KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer.readSimple(KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer.kt:85)
        at streams.kafka.KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer.read(KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer.kt:132)
        at streams.kafka.KafkaEventSink$createJob$1.invokeSuspend(KafkaEventSink.kt:95)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:235)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractContinuation.run(AbstractContinuation.kt:19)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.Task.run(Tasks.kt:94)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:586)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:732)
```

It looks like I've butchered the `SET` command. I've tried various permutations in the `SET` section, e.g. no `event` prefix, escaping the period after `event`, and removing the `event.` entirely.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Labels cannot be set from a variable, or you will have to use [APOC](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/data-creation/) .

I suggest to read the Neo4j naming rules and recommendations : https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/

Secondly, can you describe why you would like to set the IP as a label ? This doesn't make a lot of sense to be honest.

Comment: Thanks so much, @ChristopheWillemsen. I originally used the pattern strategy to build the graph (see https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/consumer/#_the_literal_pattern_literal_strategy). The nodes were labeled in the Neo4j Browser. I liked this because I could immediately recognize the IP addresses and start to interpret the graph without having to click on the nodes.

I switched to Cypher because it seems more flexible. The downside of doing this was that I lost the labels, which is why I was looking at add 'em back.

Comment: I switched to the Neovis.js (see https://medium.com/neo4j/graph-visualization-with-neo4j-using-neovis-js-a2ecaaa7c379) and it looks spectacular. Neovis.js also provides way more control over labeling, can display thousands of nodes, etc...